# How can i store that from one table to another?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-7

Hi i´m using Laravel 7 and im dealing with some issues while storing the id of a table on another table. I have a table called customers and another called contacts, where one customers may have many contacts and one contact belongs to only one customer.

Customer.php:

```
public function contacts(){
        return $this->hasMany(Contact::class);
    }
```

This is my method contact which stablishes a relationship.

And the following is my customer method in Contact.php:

```
public function customer(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Customer::class,'id_account','id'); 
    }
```

In my contact table i have a column called id_account and i want there to store the customer id. So im trying to achieve this by doing the following:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Backend;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Model\Contact;
use App\Model\Customer;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Auth;
use Session;


class ContactController extends Controller
{
    //
    public function view(){ 
        $allData = Contact::all();
        return view('backend.contact.view-contact', compact('allData'));
    }

    public function add(){ 
        $customers = Customer::all();
        $contact['customers'] = Customer::all();
        
        return view('backend.contact.add-contact', compact('customers'));
    }

    public function store(Request $request){
        $customers = Customer::all();
        $contact = new Contact();
        $contact->name = $request->name;
        $contact->lastname = $request->lastname;
        $contact->id_account = Customer::contacts('id');
        $contact->idOwner = Auth::user()->id;
        $contact->position = $request->position;
        $contact->mobile_no = $request->mobile_no;
        $contact->email = $request->email;
        $contact->save();
        Session::flash('success');
        return redirect()->route('contact.view', compact('contact','customers'));
    }
}
```

I´d tried several ways such as:

```
$contact->id_account = Customer::contacts('id');
```

Or

```
$contact->id_account = Customer::get('id');

$contact->id_account = $request->$customers->id;
```

But none of this worked, im new to Laravel and im really struggling with this issue. The different types of error were:

```
Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value: '[{"id":1}]' for column `axis`.`contacts`.`id_account` at row 1 (SQL: insert into `contacts` (`name`, `lastname`, `id_account`, `idOwner`, `position`, `mobile_no`, `email`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Mateo, Ghidini, [{"id":1}], 1, pasante, 12345678, mateo.ghidini@hotmail.com, 2021-08-05 18:31:12, 2021-08-05 18:31:12))
```

Another error:

```
Trying to get property 'id' of non-object
```

And finally:

```
Non-static method App\Model\Customer::contacts() should not be called statically



<div class="form-group col-md-6">
               <label for="account">Cuenta</label>
                <select name="account" id="" class="form-control">
                     <option value="">Seleccione el holding de la empresa</option>
                     @foreach ($customers as $key => $customer)
                     <option value="{{$customer->id}}">{{$customer->holding}}</option>
                                
                      @endforeach
                </select>
           </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you try to save you need to know exactly which `Customer`'s id to store on that row. So you can show a `<select ...>` on your form and let user select the `Customer`

In `resources/views/backend/contact/add-contact.blade.php`

```
<!-- I assume you have a form and other inputs here -->
<form>

<!-- add a select-option for Customer -->
<select name="customer_id">
    @foreach($customers as $customer)
    <option value="{{ $customer->id }}">
        {{ $customer->name }}
    </option>
    @endforeach
</select>


</form>
```

Now you can use it from your controller

```
public function store(Request $request){
    $customers = Customer::all();
    $contact = new Contact();
    $contact->name = $request->name;
    $contact->lastname = $request->lastname;
    $contact->id_account = $request->customer_id; // here we used customer_id from form
    $contact->idOwner = Auth::user()->id;
    $contact->position = $request->position;
    $contact->mobile_no = $request->mobile_no;
    $contact->email = $request->email;
    $contact->save();
    Session::flash('success', 'Contact saved to selected customer.');
    return redirect()->route('contact.view', compact('contact','customers'));
}
```

Comment: i do have the form as you showed with the same exact select and foreach, but when i try to do $contact->id_account = $request->customer_id i get 'undefined variable customer' I'll edit the question to show you.